# How know the last change date of a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I know the last change date of a stored Procedure in Sql Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select modify_date
from sys.procedures
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourProc')
```